# Existence of derivative of a given function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Given $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2x}\int_{-x}^xf(t)dt,$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f'(0)$ exists, how can I prove that $F'(0)$ also exists?

Comment: Take a look at the proof of Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: Try applying fundamental theorem of calculus. Please also outline what you have tried so far etc..

Comment: To be precise, $F'(0)$ does not exist because $F(0)$ does not exist. It is true, though, that you can extend $F$ in $0$, and speak about the derivative in $0$ of this extension.

Comment: It might be fruitful to note that $F$ is an even function.

Comment: Marc, I have taken a look at your past activity on this web site and it appears that you have the bad habit of not accepting any answer to your questions. This is a shame, since I can tell you that some of them are really good. Please note that this site works on a volunteer base, nobody gets paid for helping the others. Your attitude only discourages such volunteers, because it sends them the message that their work is not appreciated. Please take the time to go through the list of your questions and, whenever you encounter particularly good answers, accept or upvote them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We must define $F(0)$ to be able to discuss $F'(0)$. By the mean value theorem for integrals, we find that $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x)=f(0)$, so it is natural to define $F(0)=f(0)$.

**Using intuition**

Since $f$ is differentiable at zero, we could draw a tangent line there. Now, $F(x)$ is given by the average of $f$ over the symmetric interval $[-x,x]$. Thus, for $x$ close to zero it must be close to $f(0)$ (draw a picture), i.e. $F$ is locally approximately constant around zero, and hence its derivative at zero exists and is zero. That is $F'(0)=0$.

**A proof**

Since $F$ is even, we study the right-derivative at zero only. We use the definition of derivative, and write
$$
\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}=\frac{F(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{1}{2x^2}\int_{-x}^xf(t)-f(0)\,dt.
$$
Next, we note that $\int_{-x}^x tf'(0)\,dt=0$ (since the integrand is odd), so we can safely add it inside the integral. Estimating with the triangle inequality, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bigl|\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}\Bigr|&\leq \frac{1}{2x^2}\int_{-x}^x|t|\cdot\Bigl|\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}-f'(0)\Bigr|\,dt\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2x^2}\int_{-x}^x|t|\,dt\cdot \sup_{t\in[-x,x]}\Bigl|\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}-f'(0)\Bigr|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sup_{t\in[-x,x]}\Bigl|\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}-f'(0)\Bigr|\to 0
\end{aligned}
$$
as $x\to 0^+$. In the last step we used the fact that $f$ is differentiable at zero.

We conclude that $F$ is differentiable at $0$ and $F'(0)=0$.

Comment: I believe that there are some meticulous details that you quickly skip when you say that $\sup \limits _{t \in [-x, x]} \left| \frac {f(t) - f(0)} t - f'(0) \right| \to 0$. And in analysis there are precisely these nasty little details than can invalidate a whole proof.

Comment: No, it is just the definition of differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

First, $F$ is defined everywhere except for $0$. Let us extend it by continuity to a function $\tilde F$ defined in $0$ too. In order to do this, we need to show that $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} F(x)$ exists. Using L'Hospital's theorem we get

$$\lim \limits _{x \to 0} F(x) = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\int \limits _{-x} ^x f(t) \Bbb d t} {2x} = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {f(x) + f(-x)} 2 = f(0) ,$$

so me may define $\tilde F (x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} F(x), & x \ne 0 \\ f(0), & x = 0 \end{matrix} \right.$. We want to show that $\tilde F '(0)$ exists.

By definition,

$$\tilde F ' (0) = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\tilde F (x) - \tilde F (0)} {x - 0} = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {F (x) - f(0)} x = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\frac 1 {2x} \int \limits _{-x} ^x f(t) \Bbb d t - f(0)} x = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\frac 1 {2x} \int \limits _{-x} ^x f(t) \Bbb d t - \frac 1 {2x} \int \limits _{-x} ^x f(0) \Bbb d t} x = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\frac 1 {2x} \int \limits _{-x} ^x f(t) - f(0) \Bbb d t} x = \frac 1 2 \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\int \limits _{-x} ^x f(t) - f(0) \Bbb d t} {x^2} .$$

Apply L'Hospital's theorem once to get

$$\frac 1 2 \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {f(x) - f(0) + f(-x) - f(0)} {2x} = \frac 1 4 \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \left( \frac {f(x) - f(0)} x + \frac {f(-x) - f(0)} x \right) = \frac 1 4 \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \left( \frac {f(x) - f(0)} x - \frac {f(-x) - f(0)} {-x} \right) = \frac 1 4 (f'(0) - f'(0)) = 0 .$$

To conclude, $\tilde F'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(0)$ exists, $f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+o(x)$, where $o(x^n)$ 
is a function such that $\lim_{x\to0}o(x^n)=0$ and 
$\lim_{x\to0}o(x^n)/x^n$ exists (is not infinite).
Therefore
$$F(x)=\frac1{2x}\int_{-x}^x\left[f(0)+tf'(0)+o(t)\right]\mathrm dt.$$
The integral gives
$$F(x)=\frac1{2x}\left[2x\,f(0)+0+o(x^2)\right]=f(0)+o(x)$$
from that we conclude that $F(0)=f(0)$ and $F'(0)$ exists and $F'(0)=0$.

Comment: While I like "the spirit" of the proof which is straightforward, there is one issue: why is $o(t)$ integrable?

Comment: And, assuming that $o(t)$ is integrable, why is $\int \limits _{-x} ^x o(t) \Bbb d t = o(x^2)$? And why is $\frac {o(x^2)} x = o(x)$? Who says that $o$ is a power series? We don't live in the XVIII-th century anymore, mathematics have become much more complicated!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net. If $o(t)$ is not integrable, then $f$ isn't either, I only used the implicit assumption that the integral is defined.

Comment: @AlexM. The *little o* notation is a quite common notation in mathematics. $o(x^2)$ is a function such that $o(x^2)/x^2$ has a finite limit when $x\to0$. It can be anything and does not need to be a power series.  See for instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) or [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html).